# Selenium WebDriver Ruby bindings get timeout errors

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

When I run selenium webdriver ruby bindings in my site,sometimes I get **Timeout Error**.

I feel loading images waste a lot of time,how to start selenium without load images, and any way to speed up?

Comment: What do you mean? Loading without images? If the website loads slowly because of your images, it isn't just Selenium that will have this problem, it will be your users. Timeout error on what? When the first page loads? When you click a particular element? You need to provide more information, then hopefully we can give you better advice.

Comment: @Arran THANKS for your advice! the problem is loading images slowly.timeout on load page not click  particular element.so i want to Loading without images.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stop your images from loading, I believe you can create a custom Firefox profile, install an Adblock extension, save the profile, and then specify your Selenium server to start up new Firefox instances with that saved profile instead of a fresh profile. You would have to tell Adblock to block all the images on your site.

However, I agree with @Arran. If your website is loading slowly with images, you should probably be tackling other issues like increasing server resources, caching, or other techniques to speed up your load times.

You could also increase your Selenium load timeout to 150 seconds (2.5 minutes) from the default 30 seconds, but I would still recommend trying to speed up your page loads either way.